# How to make tables stack, right over left, in responsive email?

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design

So this is my second responsive design email, so I'm stuck.

I have 2 tables that I am trying to stack when viewed on mobile. Below is how the 2 tables will appear in desktop mode:

```
|  1  |  2  |
```

When viewed on mobile, I want the tables to appear as such:

```
|  2  |
|  1  |
```

I've tried floating the tables and using `position:fixed !important`  but I cant get the desired effect. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `position: fixed` has nothing to do with `float`

Comment: So the problem is what?  You don't know how to make 2 tables appear side by side or you don't know how to get them to stack on top of each other (which is the default behavior for tables)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was trying to make table 2 float above table 1 when viewed on mobile. Whenever my email went to mobile mode, table 1 would be on top. I tried forcing table 2 to go to the top with  "position:fixed" hoping it would force it to start at the top, but all it did was sit on top of table 1 (basically hiding it).

Thanks to Brett for the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I experimented with a way to do this in [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851318/is-it-possible-to-use-displayblock-on-td-in-html-email-to-achieve-responsive-t/18545107#18545107).

You can use the `dir="rtl"` to control how the columns stack. Here's an example:

```
<table class="deviceWidth" dir="rtl"  width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; ">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%" dir="ltr" align="right" class="full">
      <p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0; padding:0; margin:0;">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/440x440&text=RIGHT" alt="" border="0" style="display: block; width:100%; height:auto;" /></a> 
      </p>                  
    </td>
    <td width="50%" dir="ltr" align="left" class="full">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/440x440&text=LEFT" alt="" border="0" style="display: block; width:100%; height:auto;" /></a>                      
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Combined with an `@media` query of:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px)  {


  .full {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

Here's the full [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/3s3uc/).

Comment: I tried this in Outlook 2016, and Outlook desktop stripped away the `dir="ltr"` on any children `<table>` and `<td>`, duplicated `dir="rtl"` to children tables, and it added `dir="ltr"` on the leaf text (`<p>`, `<span>`) nodes. Has anybody tried this in Outlook with some sort of nested table setup before?

Comment: Media queries are removed in the email

Answer (score 1):

You could float them to the right and declare them in the reverse order.

```
// HTML
<table><tr><td> 2 </td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td> 1 </td></tr></table>

// CSS
table {
    float: right; 
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/GWja8/) (resize the example window)