# Push Pull Tables in Zurb INK

Tags: html, css, zurb-ink

In my INK HTML Newsletter I am creating, I have a row divided into 2 tables of six columns each. The left table is text and the right is an image. When the email is read on a mobile I would like the image to appear first and the text to appear beneath the image. In Zurb Foundation (for Sites) this can be done using push and pull. Is there a way of achieving the same effect in INK. Since INK uses tables, the problem will be swapping table cells. I tried creating inline CSS for push and pull using the code from Foundation but it just moves the cell contents to the right or left (to be expected)

Answer (score 1):

You could add this functionality yourself using [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851318/is-it-possible-to-use-displayblock-on-td-in-html-email-to-achieve-responsive-t/18545107#18545107) I came up with awhile back.

The trick is the `dir` parameter to control how the columns are displayed.

```
<table class="row" dir="rtl" >
  <tr>
    <td class="wrapper last">

      <table class="six columns">
        <tr>
          <td dir="ltr" align="right">

            [RIGHT CONTENT HERE]

           </td>
           <td class="expander"></td>
         </tr>
       </table>

     </td>
     <td class="wrapper" dir="ltr" align="left">

       <table class="six columns">
         <tr>
           <td >

             [LEFT CONTENT HERE]

           </td>
         <td class="expander"></td>
       </tr>
     </table>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

On a desktop email client this will display the first column on the right, and the second column on the left. On mobile clients that support responsive emails the first column will display above the second column.

[image: Android in landscape view]

[image: iOS in portrait view]

Answer (score 0):

Since Zurb Ink doesn't currently have the push/pull capabilities I think the closest you will come to that functionality will be to use the [visibility classes](http://zurb.com/ink/docs.php#visibility-classes).